FPS Multiplayer Template 5 doesn't work online
Unfortunately i'm having some trouble with the FPS Multiplayer Template 5 because i downloaded the template on Unreal Engine then i packaged it and i sent the .zip file to a friend to test if it worked, but when i created a session he couldn't find it. But when i tryed opening the .exe file twice on my pc when i created a session i could find it. Does it have anything to do with the SteamDevAppId in the DefaultEngine.ini of the game, do i have to change it from 480 to something else? Thanks for all the suggestions!
I tryed opening the .exe file twice on my pc when i created a session i could find it.I also followed the rules by opening steam before playing but nothing.
